# async operation on a two dimensional array in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

I have a 2D array. For each element within that array an async operation (io operation) has to be performed.

For a 1D array - I would use async.eachSeries or async.each.

What is the best way to handle this ?

Below is my current code:

```
var i = 0, j = 0;
async.eachSeries(arr, function (arrItem, eachCbk) {

  //process arrItem
  async.eachSeries(arrItem, function (arrItemItem, eachCbk) {

    //process arrItemItem
    console.log(i,j,arrItemItem);

    asyncFun(i,j, function() {
      j++;
      eachCbk();
    });

  }, function (err) {

    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    j = 0;
    i++;
    eachCbk();

  });

}, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

});
```

Comment: although code is doing the job - I feel there must be a better way to do this

Comment: The question is wether or not the next async operation depends on results from the previous one, i.e. if you need a waterfall effect, or just parallell execution.

Comment: next operations depends i.e waterfall

Comment: Since you are not mapping the results back to a 2-dimensional array, can you flatten the array first?

Comment: So not sure exactly why you want to do this async. it won't run in parallel, only intermittent of each other. But since you are doing IO operations, i'm not even sure it makes sense to do it this way. If i'm not mistaking, if node opens a FD to do some IO, it will effectively block it for other IO operations?

Comment: sorry, it can be parallel. Im in midst of integrating two applications. There are two problems : one app is like a command line application which takes lot of command line inputs (one of processed output is a 2d array) and another is Im new to this async stuff.

Comment: If it can be in parallell, it would probably be easier to just push promises to an array for each async operation, and use Promise.all to know when they are all resolved.

Comment: Assuming that your inner arrays contain dependent asynchronous operations, so do the outer array's array items, then i would start thinking to construct a workflow involving two nested reduces of promises. Or i guess one might also chose to do the same job with a clever recursive structure of promises as well.